# Is there a way to resolve System namespace conflict in auto-generated from WSDL code?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, wsdl

Very simple but quite a downer. I have (unfortunately and I can't change it) a library in my project that declares its classes in `MyCompany.System` namespace. After adding a service reference to my other library, I am getting hundreds of errors in auto-generated code because `System.*` .NET namespaces are all resolved to `MyCompany.System.*` namespace.

The problem is easy fixable by editing auto-generated code and adding `global::` to all references to `System.*`. It's perplexing though why some of auto-generated code already has that and some/most doesn't. I was not able to find any options in VS2012 to force WSDL to append `global::` automatically.

So what are my options if any?

Comment: When you add the web service reference VS2012 at some point asks for the namespace of the code to be generated. Provide a namespace there that does not conflict with the exiting ones.

Comment: It does ask that but then VS uses default namespace as a suffix for that. In other words, providing `MyService` results `MyCompany.MyService`. This is desired though - it's nice to have generated code within namespace of the project.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas, one of them might work. :)

In the project where the auto-generated code will live, first edit the Visual Studio project settings and change the default namespace for the project to something other than MyCompany.  This may stop System from being interpreted as MyCompany.System.

Try using namespace aliases:

using MyCompanySystem = MyCompany.System;

Answer (score 0):

You can use extern alias like that:
In properties of MyCompany.System dll set alias as Msystem

```
extern alias MSystem
//using statements
using MSystem.MyCompany.System
```

msdn about extern alias: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms173212.aspx